# What's the shortest time for a completed StackEgg?

Tags: discussion, stackegg

While the leaderboards show the most completed and the average time for completion, what's the shortest time for a completed StackEgg so far?

Comment: Could you also add an answer for arcade?

Comment: You may consider accepting the current leader and updating that as lower scores come in. That way people can (quickly) see what the current target is without scrolling through them all.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion, I second the motion :D

Comment: Did anybody else think it said "**StackEgg:** Hack your Stack Exchange Site" at first?

Comment: Now that [it's open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/stackegg/blob/7b367857a65582d5c4f3e4ee370f86efe6b53f09/StackEgg/StackEggPhase.cs), it should be possible to calculate the minimum time. But it's still not simple. Due to the decaying rules, even private beta has a non-obvious strategy: alternate Ask and Answer for the first six days, then on the seventh day choose Answer instead of Ask. This reduces the private beta time from 19 days to 18. There could be an even better strategy, but from looking at the numbers I doubt it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Sustainable Living, 223 Days

Way to go Sustainable Living! They managed to hatch their egg (in record time, currently) and make their way on to the global leaderboard. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8zJx.png).

Come join [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) if you want to talk strategy.

Comment: Wow, this is ROMhack hardcore. Well done!

Comment: This post is a lie, since *they* did nothing, according to you. Correct yourself.

Comment: Now try it without using a flag, as that costs 10 virtual days in the official rankings. :P

Comment: @Runer112 I intend to, if the game is still available for me to play in four hours. Even without a flag, I know I can beat this score. I made one mistake that really cost me.

Comment: @Rainbolt let us know how it goes! The game ends when it is no longer April 1st anywheres in the world

Comment: I'm confused. When I go there, they seem to be still in Beta.

Comment: @corsiKa I am not sure what hatching a StackEgg has to do with being in beta.

Comment: Oh... Right... Okay, I was thinking hatching a stack egg was slang for getting out of beta. *doh*

Answer (score 17):

## PPCG, 235 Days

Programming Puzzles and Code Golf managed 235 days. Screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2axsj.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esov5.png) (second one has our name in it). Feel free to swing by [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: [Here's another screenshot that verifies it was on PPCG.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/esov5.png)

Comment: Just for fun, [here's another](http://i.imgur.com/KH7DEtO.png).

Comment: @Jeremy Why this strange edit...

Comment: @nicael Don't worry, I rolled it back.

Answer (score 15):

## Reverse Engineering, 227 days

Happy early Easter/holiday of your choice, from PPCG. :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlOmi.png

Answer (score 7):

## Arqade, 251 Days

Answer (score 5):

## Christianity, 250 days

Not the fastest, but to submit another contender, [Christianity got 250 days](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20851662#20851662).

Comment: You mean you couldn't do it in seven?

Comment: @Rainbolt: Alas, I am not God. ... That's probably a good thing, come to think of it.

Comment: @Rainbolt lul :D

Comment: @Rainbolt Christianity.SE actually did it in 6 days, and rested for 244.

Answer (score 3):

## Blender, 252

I'm submitting **252** from [blender beta](http://blender.stackexchange.com), the fastest **beta**-site time so far.

okay, now we aren't the fastest beta, but still... close

Comment: Whoa. Arqade beat that by 1. The OP said that

Comment: Yes... but we are beta, they've got billions of users

Comment: Exactly, fastest **Beta** time

Comment: Okay, then I agree

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Don't you know? Users is the least valuable metric.

Comment: @Yawus I disagree, the leading sites have the some of the most active chats

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I was referring to StackEgg mechanics. Most strats seems to value Users least of the four (five, if you count Traffic) metrics.

Comment: Oh as a joke, yes I do know and agree with you

Comment: Until anyone shows that the number of users playing the game has a direct impact on the outcome of a given turn, it really doesn't matter whether the site is beta or not.

Comment: @Air yah... I just couldn't stop myself from posting a stat **one** under the highest, we are so proud of ourselves for clocking in such a competitive time...

Comment: I would argue that the more people there are available, the more likely the game will be continued effectively, as they can take over when one person has to leave. On a beta site, quite often there is only one (or fewer) users who can devote time to hatching the egg.

Comment: Obviously having a *really big* community like SO doesn't help because you get droves of people popping in for a few minutes/a game and voting inefficiently as a bloc.