# This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta... On Meta.SE

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, meta, locked-answers

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252511/252153) was locked (reasons are not needed for this post):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My comment is about the link "visit meta". That isn't especially helpful as we are on Meta.SE, the site it redirects us to.

Should this link be changed or removed?

Comment: Well, if we want to be super picky it can say "For more info click here" when on MSE itself but... it's really too minor to be worth the development time.

Comment: Meta is its own Meta apparently :D related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173624/post-locked-should-link-to-the-meta-faq-on-post-locking

Answer (score 12):

Where else are you supposed to discuss this stuff? There's no meta-meta; if there was, **this** question would be there, and it clearly isn't.

...or *is it?*

Comment: Perhaps it should be migrated, then?

Comment: At least have meta.meta.stackexchange.com be an alternate url for meta.stackexchange.com (and repeat to a depth of like 3 or 4 or something).

Comment: @Servy [tag:feature-request] time? :P

Comment: @Servy if we get meta.meta.stackexchange.com, it should be added to migration targets over here, shouldn't it. _Closing>Off-Topic>Migration>belongs on meta.meta.stackexchange.com_

Comment: @gnat I asked for it specifically so that I could comment on questions saying, "belongs on meta.meta.stackoverflow instead" just to mess with people.

Comment: @Servy comment is not enough: ["vote to close it immediately..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Answer (score 7):

No, the link goes to the correct place.

[Meta is its own Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86787/where-to-ask-questions-about-meta-stack-overflow?lq=1).